# Why was this question about why 'Voldemort became more snakelike' closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions

Regarding this question: [Why does Voldemort become more snakelike?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/162565/why-does-voldemort-become-more-snakelike)

The question links to the now marked duplicate here: [How did Voldemort's face get disfigured?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/how-did-voldemorts-face-get-disfigured)

The question and the post marked as a duplicate both mentions that:

> We know that Voldemort's appearance became more snakelike as he made more horcruxes and dove deeper into dark magic

which is the answer to marked duplicate.

At a glance it does seem like a dupe, I thought so myself, however this question is asking why Voldemort **became more snakelike rather than any other animal**, as opposed to **why his appearance changed**.

To me the question is not a duplicate as the linked post does not satisfy the question asked. Am I wrong in this?

Comment: Are you entirely sure that he became "*snakelike*"? The better answer on the dupe question suggests that he became deformed and that his deformity merely resembles a snake due to his face becoming flattened.

Comment: @Valorum that seems more to me like a possible answer to the closed question than it does a reason to close as a duplicate.

Comment: Honestly, it's only baaaaaarely different.

Comment: *shrug*  I'd voted to leave it open, since it had linked the apparent dupe already and was attempting to be distinct, and I didn't see any direct answers already posted from the dupe (although Valorum raises a fair point).